# How can I get out of vlock on new archlinux VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, archlinux

I was trying to display the time to see if I had the timezone correct... instead of the command 'clock'(which I know is not right now) I used 'vlock'. This locked my terminal while I was setting up archlinux. Now I am stuck on a screen that says

"The tty1 is now locked by root. Use Alt-function keys to switch to other virtual consoles.
Password:"

And I do not remember setting up a password so I do not know how I could guess correctly. Is there a way to undo the vlock? or should I just start a new archlinux VM?

Comment: Switch to another virtual console (Alt+F2) and kill the `vlock` process running in the first console.

Comment: Now I am being prompted for a username and password.. the "archiso login"

Comment: I just typed root in as the archiso login and it worked. Thanks!